# Is there something non-secure with serialization?

Tags: java, security, encryption, serialization

I came across [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076837/mobile-java/twelve-rules-for-developing-more-secure-java-code.html) which states:

"Rule 9: Make your classes nonserializeable

Serialization is dangerous because it allows adversaries to get their hands on the internal state of your objects."

While I can understand what the author is saying, why could one not just encrypt any serialized data? If serializing allowing data to be serialized is not secure, what is the proper alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the author meant that you should make your classes non-serializable *by default*. That said, if you intentionally want to serialize your class - go ahead and do so.

As for alternatives, you can create json/xml representation of the *state* of your object - without giving away the internals of the implementation.

You can also encrypt the bits, like you suggested. A simple demo of how to do it by using a bit rotation can be found in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things1/).

Comment: That is a very satisfying link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Item 76 in Chapter 11 of Bloch, Effective Java, covers this.  You need to be careful reading back a serialised class, in case somebody has altered it since it was created.  Basically you need a defensive `readObject()` method.